# Conditional Formatting On An Excel Range For Each Cell To Have an Up Arrow Icon Regardless of Value Contained

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, conditional-formatting

My goal is to highlight a section of an Excel Range (*which I can do with conditional formatting*) but now it also needs to add up-arrows to each cell within that aforementioned range.

How does one do that?

---

What I have tried is something like this

```
var wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
var formatIcon = rngExistingColumns.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition() as Excel.IconSetCondition;
formatIcon.Formula = "=1";
formatIcon.IconSet = wb.IconSets[Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Arrows];

var crit1 = formatIcon.IconCriteria;

crit1[1].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueFormula;
crit1[1].Operator = (int) Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater;
crit1[1].Value = 0;
```

But I do not get any results and only get com exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Do not manually set the rule for red icon `crit1[1]` because the red icon is the last rule against green/yellow icon rules.

My sample code works, and it just sets green/yellow rules. Value 60 will be yellow , value 80 and 90 will be green, the other will be red.

```cs
var wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A1"].Value2 = "20";
wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A2"].Value2 = "80";
wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A3"].Value2 = "60";
wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A4"].Value2 = "40";
wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A5"].Value2 = "30";
wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A6"].Value2 = "90";

// Add an icon set condition to the range
Excel.IconSetCondition iconSetCondition1 =
    (Excel.IconSetCondition)
    wb.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "A6"].
    FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition();

iconSetCondition1.SetFirstPriority();
iconSetCondition1.ShowIconOnly = false;

iconSetCondition1.IconSet =
    Excel.XlIconSet.xl3Arrows;

var yellowIcon = iconSetCondition1.IconCriteria[2];
yellowIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
yellowIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;
yellowIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(60);

var greenIcon = iconSetCondition1.IconCriteria[3];
greenIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
greenIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;
greenIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(80);
```

2020/08/25 **Update**
If you want the top rule is red, second rule is green, the last is yellow, you can set `Icon` to change the rule orders.

For my example, Value 60 will be green, value 80 and 90 will be red, the other will be yellow.

```cs
var greenIcon = iconSetCondition1.IconCriteria[2];
greenIcon.Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconGreenCircle;
greenIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
greenIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;
greenIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(60);

var redIcon = iconSetCondition1.IconCriteria[3];
redIcon.Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconRedCircle;
redIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
redIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;
redIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(80);

var yellowIcon = iconSetCondition1.IconCriteria[1];
yellowIcon.Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconYellowCircle;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `crit[1]` it appears to be the first one set above, but doesn't have an operator or value.